# How to compare two Date Strings in "EEE Mon dd hh:mm:ss TMZ yyyy" format in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm getting two Strings(dates) in `EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss TMZ yyyy` format, I want to compare those two dates in Javascript/Jquery.

Example strings : `Fri Aug 14 13:12:45 CDT 2020, Tue Aug 25 05:33:19 CDT 2020`

Comment: Use a real date library, because datetime maths _is impossibly hard_. [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is the de-facto solution in JS land.

Comment: Thank prime for other people working out the hard problems (and sharing their code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to parse the dates into a Javascript date object. With the format you're mentioning a simple `new Date(longstringdateformat)` would work. Then you can compare the value in milliseconds from the `getTime()` method.

```
function compareDates(){
     const date1 = new Date("Fri Aug 14 13:12:45 CDT 2020");
     const date2 = new Date("Tue Aug 25 05:33:19 CDT 2020");
     return date1.getTime()-date2.getTime();
}
```

here if the return value is negative date2 is greater than date1, if it's positive date2 is lesser than date1 and if it is 0 they are equal.